# How to write retrofit function for the following

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, form-data

How can I write a retrofit function to receive the following api call. I have only called retrofit functions where we pass parameters directly in params and not in body form-data so I don't know how to do this.

[image]

Although it's not right at all, This is what I have tried :

This is my mainActivity-

```
private void login(String username, String password) {

        Call<User> call = student_signin.apiInterface.studentLogin("json",username, password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

                if (response.body().getError_code() == "401") {

                    Toast.makeText(student_signin.this, response.body().getError_message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (!response.body().getU_id().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(student_signin.this, "user signed in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(student_signin.this,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my APIinterface class-

```
public interface APIinterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login")
    Call<User> studentLogin(@Query("format") String format, @Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);

}
```

This is my APIclient class-

```
public class APIclient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.example.com/api/xyz/";
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getApiClient()
    {
        if(retrofit==null)
        {
            //   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

And this is my model class-

```
public class User {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("u_id")
    private String u_id;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("customer_id")
    private String customer_id;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("error_code")
    private String error_code;

 public String getU_id() {
        return u_id;
    }

    public String getCustomer_id() {
        return customer_id;
    }

    public String getError_code() {
        return error_code;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and acknowledged.

Comment: give us your all json object

Comment: The json object is simple like this:

Comment: you want to code in java or cotlin?

Comment: java @SideegMoHammed

Comment: @SideegMoHammed [ { "u_id": "15", "customer_id": "","error_code:"" } ]

Answer (score 0):

```
@POST("/api/xyz/login")
    fun getData(@Body params: JsonObject): JsonObject


client.getData(JsonObject().apply {
            addProperty("advice_id", adviceId)
            addProperty("content", content)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to send the user name and password as pram in method getData() and revice the json as user list

```
@GET("/api/xyz/login")
Call<List<User>> getData(@Query("user_name") String userName,@Query("password") String password);
```

Comment: And where will I pass the parameters username and password ?